# Monitoring and providing web client notifications on lambda function progress?

Tags: javascript, java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

If we want to provide progress notifications for a lambda function to a web client how is that done?  In other words we want to send percentage complete updates incrementally until the the job is complete, at which point we return the result of the function.

One of the links on Amazon's forum said use SNS?  In that case what would the process be for setting that up?